# JFrox Xray installation on Windows server

Tags: devops, artifactory, jfrog-xray, devsecops

I Have JFrog Artifactory installed and up and running on Windows 2012 R2, now i want to install JFrog-Xray on the same server and linking with existing Artifactory instance, is it possible ?

As per JFrog documentation, XRay installer available only for for Docker runtime and Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the official [JFrog Xray Installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Xray) docs, Xray cannot be installed on Windows directly.

There are two options here

- Setup a Linux VM running in the same server and install Xray on it
- Setup a separate, Linux based server and install Xray on it

You can also install both Artifactory and Xray together in the same Linux server or a Kubernetes (Linux) installation.

I know this answer does not provide a clean Xray on Windows solution, but does provide a viable option that is production grade.